# mongodb query to get related data from relational collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 6 collections:
    A,B,C,D,E and F

- the A collection has many relations with B collection:

  - one side is A collection.
  - many side is B collection.
  - collection A with `coll_B_list` field is connected to collection B.
  - collection B with `coll_A` field is connected to collection A.

collection A:

```
[
    {id:"a1", coll_B_list:["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"]},
    {id:"a2", coll_B_list:["b5", "b6", "b7", "b8"]}
]
```

- the B collection has one relation with collections C,D,E and F.

  - collection B with the `coll_C` field is connected to collection C.
  - collection B with the `coll_D` field is connected to collection D.
  - collection B with the `coll_E` field is connected to collection E.
  - collection B with the `coll_F` field is connected to collection F.
  - the collections C, D, E and F with the `coll_B` field are connected to collection B.

collection B:

```
[
    {id:"b1", date:"2020-06-01", coll_A:"a1", coll_C:"c1", coll_D:"d2"},
    {id:"b2", date:"2020-07-01", coll_A:"a1", coll_C:"c2"},
    {id:"b3", date:"2020-05-01", coll_A:"a1", coll_C:"c3", coll_D:"d3", coll_E:"e1", coll_F:"f1"},
    {id:"b4", date:"2020-08-01", coll_A:"a1", coll_C:"c4", coll_D:"d1", coll_E:"e2"},
    {id:"b5", date:"2020-04-01", coll_A:"a2", coll_C:"c5", coll_D:"d4", coll_E:"e3"},
    {id:"b6", date:"2020-01-01", coll_A:"a2", coll_C:"c6", coll_D:"d5", coll_E:"e4", coll_F:"f2"},
    {id:"b7", date:"2020-10-01", coll_A:"a2", coll_C:"c7"},
    {id:"b8", date:"2020-09-01", coll_A:"a2", coll_C:"c8", coll_D:"d6"}
]
```

collection C:

```
[
    {id:"c1", coll_B:"b1", value:"v1"},
    {id:"c2", coll_B:"b2", value:"v2" },
    {id:"c3", coll_B:"b3", value:"v3" },
    {id:"c4", coll_B:"b4", value:"v4" },
    {id:"c5", coll_B:"b5", value:"v5" },
    {id:"c6", coll_B:"b6", value:"v6" },
    {id:"c7", coll_B:"b7", value:"v7" },
    {id:"c8", coll_B:"b8", value:"v8" }
]
```

collection D:

```
[
    {id:"d1", coll_B:"b4", value:"v9" },
    {id:"d2", coll_B:"b1", value:"v10" },
    {id:"d3", coll_B:"b3", value:"v11" },
    {id:"d4", coll_B:"b5", value:"v12" },
    {id:"d5", coll_B:"b6", value:"v13" },
    {id:"d6", coll_B:"b8", value:"v14" }
]
```

collection E:

```
[
    {id:"e1", coll_B:"b3", value:"v15" },
    {id:"e2", coll_B:"b4", value:"v16" },
    {id:"e3", coll_B:"b5", value:"v17" },
    {id:"e4", coll_B:"b6", value:"v18" }
]
```

collection F:

```
[
    {id:"f1", coll_B:"b3", value:"v19" },
    {id:"f2", coll_B:"b6", value:"v20" }
]
```

I want Query that its result be like this:

`coll_B_list` field should :

1. sorted descending base on `date` field.
2. in the collections C,D,E and F :

   ```
       - if exist related collection then show that
       - else show the nearest collection
   ```

Result:

```
[
    {
        id:"a1",
        coll_B_list:[
            {
                id:"b4", 
                date:"2020-08-01", 
                coll_C:{id:"c4", value:"v4"}, 
                coll_D:{id:"d1", value:"v9"}, 
                coll_E:{id:"e2", value:"v16"}, 
                coll_F:{id:"f1", value:"v19"}       // doesnt exist so get the nearest value
            },
            {
                id:"b2", 
                date:"2020-07-01", 
                coll_C:{id:"c2", value:"v2"}, 
                coll_D:{id:"d2", value:"v10"},      // doesnt exist so get the nearest value
                coll_E:{id:"e1", value:"v15"},      // doesnt exist so get the nearest value
                coll_F:{id:"f1", value:"v19"}       // doesnt exist so get the nearest value
            },
            {
                id:"b1", 
                date:"2020-06-01", 
                coll_C:{id:"c1", value:"v1"}, 
                coll_D:{id:"d2", value:"v10"}, 
                coll_E:{id:"e1", value:"v15"},      // doesnt exist so get the nearest value
                coll_F:{id:"f1", value:"v19"}       // doesnt exist so get the nearest value
            },
            {
                id:"b3", 
                date:"2020-05-01", 
                coll_C:{id:"c3", value:"v3"}, 
                coll_D:{id:"d3", value:"v11"}, 
                coll_E:{id:"e1", value:"v15"}, 
                coll_F:{id:"f1", value:"v19"}       // doesnt exist so get the nearest value
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id:"a2",
        coll_B_list:[
            {
                id:"b7", 
                date:"2020-10-01", 
                coll_C:{id:"c7", value:"v7"}, 
                coll_D:{id:"d6", value:"v14"},      // doesnt exist so get the nearest value
                coll_E:{id:"e3", value:"v17"},      // doesnt exist so get the nearest value
                coll_F:{id:"f2", value:"v20"}       // doesnt exist so get the nearest value
            },
            {
                id:"b8", 
                date:"2020-09-01", 
                coll_C:{id:"c8", value:"v8"}, 
                coll_D:{id:"d6", value:"v14"},
                coll_E:{id:"e3", value:"v17"},      // doesnt exist so get the nearest value
                coll_F:{id:"f2", value:"v20"}       // doesnt exist so get the nearest value
            },
            {
                id:"b5", 
                date:"2020-04-01", 
                coll_C:{id:"c5", value:"v5"}, 
                coll_D:{id:"d4", value:"v12"}, 
                coll_E:{id:"e3", value:"v17"}, 
                coll_F:{id:"f2", value:"v20"}       // doesnt exist so get the nearest value
            },
            {
                id:"b6", 
                date:"2020-01-01", 
                coll_C:{id:"c6", value:"v6"}, 
                coll_D:{id:"d5", value:"v13"}, 
                coll_E:{id:"e4", value:"v18"}, 
                coll_F:{id:"f2", value:"v20"}
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

[COLLECTIONS IN MONGOPLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZeZcUiEME6U)

[NESTED $lookup in MONGOPLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xdUmL5YzJTV)

[NESTED $lookup in MONGOPLAYGROUND That Sorted](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6MDI4T4kXET)